# How to draw a bode plot for this function?

Tags: bode-plot

How do we draw the phase and amplitude diagram for the function below?

$$T(s)=\frac{100(s+10)}{s(4s+1)\cdot(s+25)}$$

I cant seem to figure this one. I found the zeros and the poles like I usually do in bode plots but I dont know how to build the diagrams.

Comment: Are you able to normally draw bode plots from the formula or would any equation in s give you problems?

Comment: I think you should ask here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is the pole at the origin causing you the confusion?

Answer (score 3):

That transfer function can be rewritten as

$$H(s)=\frac{40}{s}.\frac{1}{\frac{s}{0.25}+1}.(\frac{s}{10}+1).\frac{1}{\frac{s}{25}+1}$$

Each term leads to a asymptote with +-20 dB/decade inclination on semi-log scale. The figure below shows two magnitude plots (handwritten and software based):

[image]

Now, I leave you working on the phase plot...

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram Alpha has you covered](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Bode%5B100%2a%28s%2b10%29/%28s%2a%284s%2b1%29%2a%28s%2b25%29%29%5D)

But you could start here if you want to draw it by hand: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot